# How to get the private key & wallet address using a multi-wallet recovery seed phrase?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, seed, javascript

How can I „convert“ a 12-words-long multi wallet seed phrase *(of the Blockchain.com wallet)* to the wallets **private key** and the wallets **address** using any programming language?

The given multi wallet seed phrase is like I mentioned above from Blockchain.com. The derivation path is (to my knowledge) `m/44'/0'/n'`.

Help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [bcoin](https://bcoin.io) library.

```js
'use strict';

const bcoin = require('bcoin');
const m = bcoin.Mnemonic.fromPhrase('abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon about');
const master = bcoin.HDPrivateKey.fromMnemonic(m);
const key0 = master.derivePath("m'/44'/0'/0'/0/0");

const ring0 = new bcoin.KeyRing({privateKey: key0});
console.log('Legacy: ', ring0.getAddress('base58'));

const ring1 = new bcoin.KeyRing({privateKey: key0});
ring1.witness = true;
console.log('SegWit: ', ring1.getAddress('string'));
```

Output:

```
Legacy:  1LqBGSKuX5yYUonjxT5qGfpUsXKYYWeabA
SegWit:  bc1qmxrw6qdh5g3ztfcwm0et5l8mvws4eva24kmp8m
```